# Why is this curve contained in a plane?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves

> Suppose $\sigma:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and is of class at least $C^2$.
> Suppose for all $t \in [a,b]$ we have that
> $$\dim \operatorname{Span}_{\mathbb{R}}\{\sigma(t),\sigma'(t),\sigma''(t)\}=2$$
> and that $\sigma(t)$ and $\sigma'(t)$ are linearly independent. How can I prove that there exists a plane $\Pi$ such that $\sigma([a,b]) \subset \Pi$?

**My attempt:**

I tried computing the binormal vector $b(t)=\frac{\sigma'(t) \wedge \sigma''(t)}{\|\sigma'(t) \wedge \sigma''(t)\|}=\frac{a(t)}{|a(t)|}\frac{\sigma'(t) \wedge \sigma(t)}{\|\sigma'(t) \wedge \sigma(t)\|}$ where $a(t)$ is such that $\sigma''(t)=a(t)\sigma(t)+c(t)\sigma'(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Given what you've done so far,
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(\sigma(t)\wedge\sigma'(t))&=\sigma'(t)\wedge\sigma'(t)+\sigma(t)\wedge\sigma''(t)\\
&=c(t)(\sigma(t)\wedge\sigma'(t))\\
\implies \sigma(t)\wedge\sigma'(t)&=e^{\int_0^tc(s)ds}(\sigma(0)\wedge\sigma'(0))\\
\implies \frac{(\sigma(t)\wedge\sigma'(t))}{\| (\sigma(t)\wedge\sigma'(t))\|}&= \frac{(\sigma(0)\wedge\sigma'(0))}{\| (\sigma(0)\wedge\sigma'(0))\|}\ \text{ for all }\ t\ge0\ .
\end{align}